# Telegram URL schema: which url to trigger the client to open the "share/send to" dialogue

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am working on an telegram bot, and looking for the exact URL schema to popup the "Share / Select Group / Send to" dialogue in the telegram client.

I have seen this link in @pollbot, for which I took following screenshots.

[image: When click this link, Telegram client will popup send to dialogue]

---

A bit more details:

1. What I want is to give end-user an easy way to add the bot to their group, just like what PollBot does: When a poll being created, PollBot will return a special like to the user. Any by clicking that link, the user could easily add PollBot to a group. So I'm looking for the exact URL schema of that link.
2. I then check that link PollBot sent to me in telegram web client, and found out it's a `tg` protocol url: `tg://resolve?domain=PollBot&amp;startgroup=5148bed5f90678b93246464b3e132052`. So I tried to resend this url via bot.sendMessage. But it turned out Telegram api server won't parse the `tg://resolve` url.
3. So, how could the bot manage to send such a link to the user?

Comment: What do you want to send? Text? URL? Bot start token?

Comment: what your question is? you are about [deep linking](https://core.telegram.org/bots#deep-linking)? `https://telegram.me/BOT_USER_NAME?startgroup=vCH1vGWJxfSeofSAs0K5PA` where hash was generated by yourself to identified user who are open the link.

Comment: @Sean: I want to give end-user an easy way to add the bot to their group, just like what PollBot does: When a poll being created, PollBot will return a special like to the user. Any by clicking that link, the user could easily add PollBot to a group. So I'm looking for the exact URL schema of that link.

Comment: @dzNET I don't think that is deep linking. Because a link that can open the "share" dialogue on telegram client is of such a URL schema: "tg://resolve?domain=PollBot&amp;startgroup=5148bed5f90678b93246464b3e132052" . I have tried send such url through bot.sendMessage, and found telegram api server will parse the tg protocol.

Comment: I'm sure it's a deep linking. you should use `https` protocol, not `tg`. can you checkout this thing?

Comment: Also you can try `tg://t.me/`

Comment: How are you doing, @teleme.io? 

I have just re-read and clearly understand your question. have you found a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The link there works with deeplinking, please read about it here:
https://core.telegram.org/bots#deep-linking

the url has the following scheme:

```
https://telegram.me/<YourBotUsername>?startgroup=<Payload>
```

the `startgroup` part (parameter) of the url tells telegram to open the 'add to group' dialog.
when you choose a group there (and you can add bot's to it) the bot will be added to the group and `/start PAYLOAD` will be send to that group.
The `Payload` is what you defined as value of the `startgroup` parameter, so your bot can assosiate it with something and send the matching reply.

please mind, that the `Payload` can only contain certain characters and don't mind that the telegram clients might internaly convert that link to an tg:// url.

you can also use `start` instead of `startgroup` to open a private chat.

Comment: This is the exact answer I'm looking for, thank you so much.

Comment: Hi @teleme.io! I know `tg://resolve?domain=dznet`  
that link will be handled by your system preference application. 

you can edit this settings in your window manager configuration.

Comment: @dzNET yes, but these tg:// links are platform/client-specific and meant for client-internal use... they don't work with every client, so better don't use them... also teleme.io wanted to use deep-linking... these tg:// links don't work for deep-linking...

Comment: i has been used this auth link today:

`tg://resolve?domain=someone_bot&start=auth_abcd90ef`

Comment: and? that doesn't change the fact... why not just use the officially supported way of making such urls (deep-linking) instead of urls which is may not be supportet by every client?!?
using such a `tg://resolve` url has no benefit at all... it is just more confusing, probably not compatible with every client and not user-friendly at all...